# Ambiguity between "const char*" and "Platform::String^" constructors in cpp on UWP

Tags: string, constructor, uwp, constants, c++-cx

I have a problem with constructors in a class I'm trying to write for UWP in c++. Here's a minimal version of it :

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        inline MyClass() {}

        inline MyClass(const char* s) : version(1) { }

        inline MyClass(Platform::String^ s) : version(2) { }

    private:
        int version;
};
```

I'm working in the default UWP blank project in Visual Studio 2017.
I want to be able to write this :

```
MyClass s1 = MyClass("hello");
MyClass s2 = "hello";
MyClass s3 = (MyClass)"hello";
```

But the compiler throws 3 errors on those 3 lines :

```
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'MyClass'
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'MyClass'
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'MyClass'
note: Conversion requires a constructor or user-defined-conversion operator, which can't be used by const_cast or reinterpret_cast
```

If I add the "explicit" keyword to the Platform::String constructor like this :

```
      explicit inline MyClass(Platform::String^ s) : version(2) { }
```

then the second error C2440 'initializing' disappears, MyClass s2 = "hello" works but the others errors are still there.

I need to construct my class from both "Platform::String^" and standard "const char*".

For an unknown reason I think that there is some kind of automatic possible conversion from hard-coded strings like "hello" and Platform::String^ that result on an ambiguity at compilation time.

In example writing :

```
MyClass s0 = MyClass((const char *)"hello");
```

is working like a charm ! No more ambiguity as it is really cast to a "const char *". But I don't want to have to write this cast each time.

Does someone have an idea on how to solve this ?

Thanx by advance !

Comment: @NeilButterworth FYI, if you see `System::`, or `gcnew` or .NET in the post, it means C++/CLI, but if you see `Platform::` or UWP then that's C++/CX instead.

Comment: Yeah, passing string literal will invoke `__abi_winrt_CreateFastPassSystemStringFromLiteral` creating `String`.

Comment: There is an implicit conversion from char* to Platform::String, strings would be hard to use in a C++/CX program if that was not the case.  So the constructors are ambiguous.  It is just a mistake to provide one with an interop type argument, it should only be used in code that you expose to other modules.  A public ref class.  Convert it to std::wstring as soon as possible.  Do note that these practices are very different from the way you'd write C++/CLI code.  C++/CX is just very different, it is all pure native code without a huge support runtime library to help.

Comment: @HansPassant is there a way to desactivate these implicit conversions or to overload constructors or operator in a more precise way to allow the compiler to choose my constructors when needed ? (I'm working on a wide cross-platform solution and I want the end developpers to concentrate on other things than a String problem only on UWP)

Comment: It was just a bad design choice, no need to do anything dramatic about the way the language works.